# Loading google map polygon on IE slowly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, polygon

everyone. Recently, we have faced one problem about the speed of loading google map components on different broswer. Regarding to the function , we have added 120 polygons, 360 sector ( also polygon ) and several attributes which attach to components on the map. The verson of JS tool is Google Map Javascript V3.

Now, this module is running fast and smoothly on Chrome and Foxfire broswer. **HOWEVER**, terreble problem would occur on **IE8 or IE9**. The process about loading informations into map becomes very **slow**, also during the period of dragging or zooming the map, which can not be accepted by users.

So, is there any solution about acceleration in this situation ?

Thank you very much for any reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it's just IE being IE.

I would suggest scaling down the number of polygons you need to show at one time by using the map bounds as the criteria to filter by. You'll still end up running into issues if you let the users zoom out to show the whole map so you may want to limit zoom levels as well.

If you take all the points that make up your polygon and push(extend) them to a LatLngBounds you can grab the bounding box and check to see if the center of that bounding box is in the map's current bounds.

Comment: Thank you truely for this answer. Yes, IE just performs like IE that we can't modify recently. Your suggestion about controling zoom is suitable but it would go against the main function of module. In fact, I have used some adaptive solutions to update loading speed, for example, the program would catch the parameters of map's current bounds as user's dragging the map, then the target polygon whose points just locates in the current bounds would show on the map. However, just like you said, when users zoom out to show the whole map, the program is forced to show all the graph at low speed.

Comment: You might also try simplifying your polygons by crunching them with the  Douglas-Peucker algorithm. If they are very complex this may help.